# Entity Framework Build Issue in VS 2012 .NET 4.5

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, msbuild, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

Is there any trick/workaround/known "gotcha" regarding Entity Framework 4 and Visual Studio 2012?

I have a project that works and compiles perfectly on my Windows 7, VS 2010, .NET 4 box.  Over the weekend I setup a new machine, with Windows 8 Enterprise RTM, and VS 2012 Ultimate RTM.  EF design is out of the box, using ObjectContext approach (pre EF 4.1).

I retrieved the working solution from source control, went through conversion process, and get it to build successfully in VS2012 targeting the .NET 4 Framework.

However, when I run the app or debug it, I get **"unable to load metadata resource"** from the first EF call. Soo ..

**Step 1: Work the EF error**

Ok, so I use dotPeek to see the assembly, and sure enough when built in VS2012, ***the EDMX metadata files are not in the assembly.***

**Step 2: work the missing resources problem**

- I set metadata processing to "copy to output" and then back to "embed" to force.  Nope.
- I looked around the MSBUILD files for 4.5 to see if the EntityDeploy targets looked corrupt.  Nope.
- I did a full repair on VS 2012 to see if something got messed up.  Nope.
- Set MSBUILD VS version to "11.0" to avoid the 2010 compatibility checks in the csproj.  Nope.

**Step 3: Delete model, try again using VS 2012 defaults**

Ok, I figured I just couldnt make this work. So I deleted the model, and readded as new in VS 2012, which uses EF 5.0 from NuGet, and recontructs using the DbContext approach.  Got all this lined up, fixed a few syntax things b/t EF 4.0 and 5.0 and we are building.

Still get same error, *still no resources in .DLL*

A collegue of mine can build this successful in VS 2012 but on Windows 7 w/o .NET 4.5 installed.

Is there a bug or known issue in .NET 4.5 or MSBUILD 4.5?  gotta be missing someting simple.

Comment: I applaud you for being so calm with this issue. I am having the same silly problem and nothing is working other than deleting the edmx file and starting over.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  I don't have a .resources file in this project and it appears CoreCompile in .NET 4.5 is not embedding any of the EF resources files without that being present.

Trying to research is this is expected or new behavior.

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer to this issue. I experienced the same thing going from Win7 / VS2010 to Win8 / VS2012. I added a resource file (.resx) to the root of my class library project and everything started working!